# program crashes in android studio while writing funtion with loops

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, if-statement

I got a problem in mainActivity.kt
The program starts perfectly but after I click any button(which needs check() function) the program stops responding and it closes. I have created wincombination with mutable list.
and firtsplayer and secondplayer.
var `firstPlayer` = `ArrayList`()
var `secondPlayer` = `ArrayList`<Int>()
`private val wincombination = listOf( listOf(1,2,3), listOf(4,5,6), listOf(7,8,9), listOf(1,4,7), listOf(2,5,8),` listOf`(3,6,9), listOf(1,5,9),` listOf`(3,5,7) )`
after play game firstplayer and secondplayer have their numbers like this [5, 4, 6]
and in function check(),i have for loop to see if there is match in firstplayer components and wincombination.it's my fun check()

```
private fun check() {
    for (i in 0..7){
        if(wincombination[i].contains(secondPlayer[0]) && wincombination[i].contains(secondPlayer[1]) &&
            wincombination[i].contains(secondPlayer[2])){
            score.add(1,1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "0 is winner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    for (i in 0..7){
        if(wincombination[i].contains(firstPlayer[0]) && wincombination[i].contains(firstPlayer[1]) &&
            wincombination[i].contains(firstPlayer[2])){
            score.add(0,1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "X is winner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    if (firstPlayer.size+secondPlayer.size==9){
        Toast.makeText(this, "it's draw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

i tried writing check function with if statements,where i write some of the combination separately.
programs works fine.
here is check funtion with if statements

```
private fun check()  {
        var winnerPlayer=0
        if (firstPlayer.contains(1) && firstPlayer.contains(2) && firstPlayer.contains(3)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(1) && secondPlayer.contains(2) && secondPlayer.contains(3)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }

        if (firstPlayer.contains(4) && firstPlayer.contains(5) && firstPlayer.contains(6)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(4) && secondPlayer.contains(5) && secondPlayer.contains(6)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }

        if (firstPlayer.contains(7) && firstPlayer.contains(8) && firstPlayer.contains(9)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(7) && secondPlayer.contains(8) && secondPlayer.contains(9)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }

        if (firstPlayer.contains(1) && firstPlayer.contains(4) && firstPlayer.contains(7)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(1) && secondPlayer.contains(4) && secondPlayer.contains(7)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }

        if (firstPlayer.contains(2) && firstPlayer.contains(5) && firstPlayer.contains(8)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(2) && secondPlayer.contains(5) && secondPlayer.contains(8)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }
        if (firstPlayer.contains(3) && firstPlayer.contains(6) && firstPlayer.contains(9)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(3) && secondPlayer.contains(6) && secondPlayer.contains(9)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }
        if (firstPlayer.contains(1) && firstPlayer.contains(5) && firstPlayer.contains(9)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(1) && secondPlayer.contains(5) && secondPlayer.contains(9)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }
        if (firstPlayer.contains(3) && firstPlayer.contains(5) && firstPlayer.contains(7)){
            winnerPlayer = 1
        }

        if (secondPlayer.contains(3) && secondPlayer.contains(5) && secondPlayer.contains(7)){
            winnerPlayer = 2
        }
        if (winnerPlayer==1){
            score.add(0,1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "X is winner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else if(winnerPlayer==2){
            score.add(1,1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "0 is winner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
```

how can i work this code with for loop?
does it need some other additional?

Comment: You need to look at the stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: doesn't show anything